# where to store the secret keys and app ids in front end angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, web-frontend

I am making a front end angular app with rails apis, but how can i store my ids and secret keys like:

Facebook app id, access token, gplus id and others..please suggest me a solution

Comment: Create a JS file and store all your keys and api ids in that js file and encrypt them.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi to decrypt you would need to put the key into the frontend which is defeating the purpose of encryption

Comment: Why to decrypt? have original js file with you and whenever there is a change encrypt and upload to server.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi can you please give an example so that the things will get more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can store either in

> HTML5 Web Storage (localStorage/sessionStorage) or  Cookies

Please got through this blog post it will give comparison study of each

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/